# How to setting font-weight under 100?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

when I increase font size 0 to 30px. It increased the font-size as well as font-weight too. But, I want to only increase font-size without increasing font-weight.
The below Image is when I increase the font-size.

[image]

However, I want to make it like this one.

[image]

Could you help me with this? It would be really appreciated it!

Comment: It depends on the font. You could try one with thin letters.

Comment: As @Azu points out, you are using a different font family than the font in your expected outcome. You don't have many options besides changing the font to something that has a lighter font weight - or you could try the answer I provided, which essentially fakes a thinner font using a text-stroke.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `-webkit-text-stroke` - despite the prefix, [it works in all browsers besides IE.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke#browser_compatibility)

The one draw back is that your text would have to be on a solid color.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}

h1.stroke {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
}
```

```html
<h1>안녕 친구!</h1>

<h1 class="stroke">안녕 친구! stroke</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a value under the 100 is not possible, but your could try to use this:

```
font-weight: lighter !important;
```

Remember to catch your tags with an ID or some classes to do more priority to your css code. Maybe your problem is an override.

For example:

```
//CSS selector specificity = 111
p#yourId.firstClass{
  font-weight: 300;   //this style is applied
}

//CSS selector specificity = 100
#yourId{
  font-weight: 100;   //this is overridden by the first
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [**`transform: scale(.5, 1);`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), which will set the text to be 50% normal width, but 100% normal height, and then you can set font-size to something large enough for you.  In addition, your text seems to be a bit opaque, so I'm also setting `opacity` to `0.7`, but you might not want that...

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: scale(.50, 1);
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, friend!  안녕 친구!</p>
```

Or, make it even thinner, at 0.25/1 ratio....

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  transform: scale(.25, 1);
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, friend!  안녕 친구!</p>
```